# Registry Defragmenter

Tags: windows, winapi

This is out of curiosity, but I have seen several (and some of them very popular) software called registry defragmenter. While I can see the benefit they offer, but I am very curious on how exactly do you do registry defragmenting? Note that I'm not asking for software name, just a basic description of how it's done programmatically. I understand there is disk defragmenting API from microsoft. Is this that they are using? Or is there "registry defragmenting" api?

Comment: Snake oil, that's what I say.

Comment: Yeah, kinda agree...  But you've gotta respect the quality of these software for they managed not to breaking their users machines so far. Btw, why WinFixer immediately came to my mind upon reading "snake oil"? :D

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060112/rewrite-registry-file-in-windows/3060729#3060729

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While disk defragmenting would be helpful, the more important speed benefit which could be obtained would be arranging the registry nodes so that a typical depth-first search would put the sequentially-accessed nodes in the same registry page.

I'm not aware of any API for that.  The algorithm is a straightforward reordering and rewriting operation, complicated by dealing with Windows' concurrent access.

Comment: Do you suggest they actually understand the registry file format? Gotta fire up my hex editor... :)

Comment: There are tools out there that read the raw registry hive files. Check out some of the open source password crackers or forensic tools.

Comment: The registry file format is nothing too complicated.  View the raw hex format is unenlightening, but there are some documents floating around that are more or less correct.  See http://www.sentinelchicken.com/data/TheWindowsNTRegistryFileFormat.pdf

Comment: @Anders, done! Found some "interesting" projects in sourceforge.net.

Comment: So in the end it's just moving the file content? Personally, after I learn how it is done, I don't like it. Mainly because they don't use (since there is none - I believe) official information from Microsoft. A tiny misunderstanding could easily screw up users' machines. On the other side I also respect the team behind those software for they manage not to wreaking havoc so far. :)

Comment: Well, testing such a utility is fairly easy:  Windows tends to crash and not ever boot again if the registry is munged.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect they're just defragmenting the files used to store registry information. Since the registry files are open during all normal Windows operation, a "normal" file defragmenting tool won't even touch them.

Comment: Initially I suspect that too. But like wallyk mentioned, many claim they do reordering registry nodes (as to children keys placed right next to the parent).

Comment: Btw, I have seen JkDefrag (now MyDefrag) defragmenting paging files. So ordinary defragmenting tool should be able to defrag registry files.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**: Most parse the file format directly and manually.

**There is another possible way**: Using the `RegSaveKey` and then the `RegReplaceKey` functions, which are used by the Windows Backup utility.

---

How do they prevent crashes in a live OS? Simple, they reroute API calls to the Windows `Reg*` functions and handle them themselves. Caching any changes that need to be written later. It would also be wise to hold an *exclusive lock* on the hive files.

I trust defragmenters MUCH more than I trust *optimizers*. Registry Optimizers can set untested or broken keys and enable broken features. With the mass commercialization of them, this is less of a problem. But still, with what I've seen in the past I don't trust them mucking my stable system up in ways that are too hard to pin down.